# How to transfer data packets using Expo inbuilt packages (Expo go)

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

How to transfer data packets using Expo inbuilt packages (Expo go).

I wished to use the package react-native-tcp-socket but its not available on expo go. ejected, then build times are very slow due to my PC being low end. Hence I wish any other option for data transfer like a single alphabet, between nodejs server (PC) and expo client (phone) or vice versa, and expo should be able to send data.